# Simple Java lottery program

Tags: java, arrays

My code above is to allow the user to enter how many tickets they want generated between 1-100, then the program generating random 6 numbers between 1-50 for the amount of tickets the user wants. After that, the program will generate another 6 numbers in a ticket and check how many winning numbers there are.
My problem is I want to take the users entry and number's generated for each ticket and create a 2D array. However if you take a look at my final line of code, I get an error when I try to create a section for the ticket and random number for that same ticket. The error is the 2D array not going through with the code. The array should display the random numbers with each ticket.

```
Scanner entry=new Scanner(System.in); 
    
    int ticketAmnt;
    
    do
    {
        System.out.println("How many tickets will you be generating?");
        ticketAmnt = entry.nextInt();
    }
    while(ticketAmnt<1 || ticketAmnt>100);
    
    int randomNumbers[] = new int[6];
    
    for (int i = 0; i <randomNumbers.length; i++)
    {
        randomNumbers[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 50);
    }
    
    int lottery [][] = new int [ticketAmnt][randomNumbers];
```

Comment: `randomNumbers` is an array. You cannot pass an array to the size of the array in lottery declaration.

Comment: your `randomNumbers` is an array. You can't pass an array as size of another array. Maybe you want to use `randomNumbers.length`?

Comment: @Aakash can you show me how i would do that if i want to show 6 numbers for each ticket?

Comment: "I get an error". ????

Comment: @Newusersda try to use below
`int lottery [][] = new int [ticketAmnt][randomNumbers.length];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems that I can see if I understood your problem statement correctly. I will break down the problem in parts.

> *allow the user to enter how many tickets they want generated between 1-100*

You did this part correctly. However, I would make a slight change so that the user is clear about what to do. I would include the range of values to be entered.

```
    do
    {
        System.out.println("How many tickets will you be generating (between 1 and 100)?");
        ticketAmnt = entry.nextInt();
    }
    while(ticketAmnt<1 || ticketAmnt>100);
```

> *then the program generating random 6 numbers between 1-50 for the amount of tickets the user wants*

The way I understood this is that you need to generate ***x*** sets of random numbers, where ***x*** is the number of tickets the user entered. So, if the user entered 5, the program should generate 5 sets of 6 random numbers (between 1 and 50). Your program only generates 1 set of 6 random values for the ticket. Also, random number generation could return duplicate values. Your lottery ticket shall not contain duplicate values. Therefore, you should create an array of integer `Set` to enforce against duplicate values.

The correct code should be something like this:

```
List<Set<Integer>> lottoTickets = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < ticketAmnt; i++) {
    Set<Integer> ticket = new HashSet<>();
    while (ticket.size() < 6) {
        ticket.add(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 51));
    }
    lottoTickets.add(ticket);
}
```

You will need to do the same when generating the winning numbers.

> *After that, the program will generate another 6 numbers in a ticket and check how many winning numbers there are*

I am assuming this part is where the winning numbers are generated.

```
Set<Integer> winningNumbers = new HashSet<>();
while (winningNumbers.size() < 6) {
    winningNumbers.add(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 51));
}
```

Now you need to compare each generated ticket against the winning number. The easiest way to do this is to use Java's Stream API.

```
lottoTickets.forEach(ticket -> {
    Set<Integer> result = winningNumbers.stream()
            .distinct()
            .filter(ticket::contains)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    System.out.println("Winning numbers found: " + result.size());
});
```

I added some `System.out` to visualize better the result of the program:

```
public class Lottery {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ticketAmnt = 0;
        Scanner entry = new Scanner(System.in);
        do
        {
            System.out.println("How many tickets will you be generating (between 1 and 100)?");
            ticketAmnt = entry.nextInt();
        }
        while(ticketAmnt<1 || ticketAmnt>100);
        entry.close();

        List<Set<Integer>> lottoTickets = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < ticketAmnt; i++) {
            Set<Integer> ticket = new HashSet<>();
            while (ticket.size() < 6) {
                ticket.add(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 51));
            }
            lottoTickets.add(ticket);
        }
        System.out.println("Tickets:");
        lottoTickets.forEach(ticket -> {
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            System.out.print("[");
            ticket.forEach(value -> {
                buffer.append(value + " ");
            });
            String values = buffer.toString().trim().replaceAll("\\s", ", ");
            System.out.print(values);
            System.out.println("]");
        });

        Set<Integer> winningNumbers = new HashSet<>();
        while (winningNumbers.size() < 6) {
            winningNumbers.add(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 51));
        }
        System.out.println("Winning numbers: ");
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        System.out.print("[");
        winningNumbers.forEach(value -> {
            buffer.append(value + " ");
        });
        String values = buffer.toString().trim().replaceAll("\\s", ", ");
        System.out.print(values);
        System.out.println("]");

        lottoTickets.forEach(ticket -> {
            Set<Integer> result = winningNumbers.stream()
                    .distinct()
                    .filter(ticket::contains)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
            System.out.println("Winning numbers found: " + result.size());
        });
    }
}
```

Program output:

```
Tickets:
[1, 2, 39, 9, 11, 29]
[32, 48, 17, 37, 22, 38]
[32, 33, 19, 36, 9, 42]
[3, 36, 6, 9, 43, 12]
[1, 17, 41, 9, 13, 30]
Winning numbers: 
[48, 1, 34, 5, 28, 31]
Winning numbers found: 1
Winning numbers found: 1
Winning numbers found: 0
Winning numbers found: 0
Winning numbers found: 1
```